# How to set up section, subsection and subsubsection counters correctly?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, counters

I used code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14443/how-to-increase-counter-for-subsection). But I can't still manage it correctly.

My code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{subsection}{22}

\begin{document}

  \section{Test section A}
    Test text.
    \subsection{Test subsection A.a}
      Test text.
      \subsubsection{Test subsubsection A.a.a}
        Test text.
    \subsection{Test subsection A.b}
      Test text.
      \subsubsection{Test subsubsection A.b.a}
        Test text.
      \subsubsection{Test subsubsection A.b.b}
        Test text.

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: result]

The `sections` shouldn't count. This works. The `subsections` should begin by 23 (without 0., therefore the line `\setcounter{subsection}{22}`). This doesn't work. The `subsubsections` should begin by 1 (without 0.23.). This works. Like I understood the `subsection` ''plane'' is dominated by the `section` ''plane'' thus the `subsubsection` ''plane'' by the `subsection` ''plane'' and so on. What is to do for the requested behavior?

The wished result:

[image: wish]

Thank you for your effort in advance!

Comment: I'm not quite following, but `\section` will restart all the subcounters.  If you want a subsection to start at 23, you need `\setcounter{subsection}{22}` after the corresponding `\section` command.  If you want that to happen with **every** `\section` command, that will take more finagling.  Is that the answer you're looking for?

Comment: Hello @Teepeemm! Thank you for your comment! The first is the answer (in my case I have only two `sections`). Will you write the answer or should I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you increment a counter, all of its subcounters are reset.  In this case, that means that whenever you call `\section`, any subsection counters are reset.  If you want to adjust the counter, you have to do so after the `\section`command.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

  \section{Test section A}
   \setcounter{subsection}{22}
    Test text.
    \subsection{Test subsection A.a}
      Test text.
      \subsubsection{Test subsubsection A.a.a}
        Test text.
    \subsection{Test subsection A.b}
      Test text.
      \subsubsection{Test subsubsection A.b.a}
        Test text.
      \subsubsection{Test subsubsection A.b.b}
        Test text.
 \section{Test section B}
  \subsection{Test subsection B.a}
  This subsection is back to being subsection 1.
\end{document}
```

A more difficult problem would be if you wanted your subsection to always start at 23 without needing to call `\setcounter` every time.