# How to change the numbering of the ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents

When I type the `\section` command and compile the ToC, I get numbering that starts with 0.xx and the subsections start with 0.xx.yy. How can I change this so that it instead starts with a different number, as in the following image? My current preamble is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\newlength{\IndentLevel}
\setlength{\IndentLevel}{0pt}
\newenvironment{myindent}{\advance\IndentLevel by 1em}{}
\newcommand{\ibox}[1]{\item\hspace{\IndentLevel}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\IndentLevel}{#1}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\varname}[1]{\begingroup\newmcodes@\mathit{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\title{Theory of Computing}
\author{ }
\date{ }
```

The desired result that I would like is the following: 
[image]

Comment: What you need to do is change the section/subsection counter.
[See this post here for an example.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14443/how-to-increase-counter-for-subsection)

Comment: OK, I get that I need to use ``\setcounter{}{}`` but what goes in the second set of braces? That question uses ``a,b,c,d`` but how does that relate to the numbers in the ToC?

Comment: @user83024: Your image does not represent anything similar to what you're asking in the question. Can you update the question to be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a document class - `report` - that defines `\chapter` and includes the `\chapter` number representation as part of the sectional unit numbering hierarchy. Either switch to a different document class that does not use `\chapter`, like `article`, or remove the `\chapter` representation from your counters in the following way:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

Previously, `\thesection` would have included `\thechapter.` before `\arabic{section}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  \setcounter{subsection}{28}
```

before the first \subsection{...} command. This should make your first subsection start with 29.