# How to make the output of \section invisible?

Tags: sectioning

I'm trying to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand\section[1]{
  \invisible{\oldsection[1]}
  \MyOwnSectionFormattingHere #1
}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

I want the original `\section` to do what it has to (like incrementing the counter), but print nothing.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14443/how-to-increase-counter-for-subsection

Comment: This looks like a quite bad hack. Better define your section correctly.

Comment: How do you want it to interact with the table of contents?

Comment: why not simply use `\refstepcounter` if you want to increment the counter? but latex section commands do a lot more eg prevent page breaks immediately before and after the heading, it seems that you plan to lose that?

Comment: The `\section` is already re-defined by another package in my case. And the redefined version does something only that package knows about. I simply need to make the output invisible.

Comment: it isn't about "simply" making the output invisible. The output doesn't consist only of a few visibles letters, but also of invisible things like spaces, penalties, whatsits (writing of toc and label), mark commands (for the header), destinations for links.

Comment: `\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sO{#3}m}{...}` will remove any meaning `\section` has for the class.

Comment: as far as I can see the answer here is to simply use `\renewcommand\section[1]{\refstepcounter{section}...your fomatting}`

Comment: You can put `\section` into a savebox (`\vbox`}, which will increment the counter but not write to the aux file.  You could use `\settransparency` (opacity-pro) and use `\rlap` and `\smash` to overlap the text. It would be easier just to copy the parts of `\@startsection` you want to implement and leave out the visible stuff.